# German for 'in a while'

Tags: english-to-german

I would like to know how to say 'in a while' in German.

The sentence I want to write is:

> 'I like chess, but I haven't played for a while.'

Another way of saying it could be:

> 'I like chess but I haven't played it for a long time.'

Comment: "For a while" does not mean "for a long time", but "for some time", so clarifying what you mean would be useful.

Comment: Welcome. Have you tried a translator ? It is very straightforward. For example translate.google.com does it correctly in both cases. If a question remains after trying, just post it.

Comment: @SwissCodeMen After your edit, the question title asks for '*in* a while', whereas the body asks about '*for* a while'. This should be more consistent, imo.

Comment: @Arsak The question title I haven't changed :O... The title still says 'in a while'. Or what have I changed...?

Comment: @SwissCodeMen I'm sorry, I misread the edit-history - so, my previous comment should have been addressed to Lelani Gouws, the OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The clearest translation would be

> Ich mag Schach, aber ich habe schon eine Weile lang nicht (mehr) gespielt.

Note that *"eine Weile"* is the *"a while"*, which describes a duration. The *"lang"* expresses that you haven't played for the duration.

You can say *"in einer Weile"*, which would be the direct translation, or *"für eine Weile"* as well but – without going into details – that will make only a marginal difference.

---

*Alternatives:*

> Ich mag Schach, aber ich habe schon länger nicht gespielt.

Because *"in a while"* is not specific you can replace it with *"länger"*.

> Ich mag Schach, aber ich habe lang nicht mehr gespielt.

This puts more weight into saying that it is a *long* time you haven't played chess in.

Comment: Good solution! I'd also add "mehr" after "nicht" in the first example.

Comment: @Nico Hey, mir ist aufgefallen, dass du deinen upvote zu einen downvote geändert hast. Ist an der Antwort etwas falsch bzw. nicht hilfreich?

Comment: @Nico Naja, die 10 reputation von deinen upvote sind verschwunden und ich habe -2 reputation im selben Moment erhalten. Das ist ein klares Indiz dafür, dass du den upvote in einen downvote geändert hast. Ist auch nicht schlimm, bloß ich würde gerne wissen, was ich denn besser machen kann. Lerne halt auch gerne mal dazu. Kannst es aber gerne auch für dich behalten. :-)

Comment: Nein, ich habe dir ein Upvote gegeben und es auch motiviert trotz Anmerkung. So link und schwachsinnig bin ich zum Glück nicht. Ob alle so transparent ticken, wage ich mal zu bezweifeln! Daher heißt es mathematisch: Mein Upvote - zwei anonyme Downvotes= -1, was deinem aktuellen Stand auch entspricht. Nochmal: Ich bin sehr fair, indem ich meine Downvotes immer begründe!

Comment: @Nico Alles klar, behalte es für dich.

Comment: Pass mal auf: Ich lese und bewerte -zig Antworten. Wenn ich deine scheiße gefunden hätte, hätte ich keinen positiven Kommentar oben geschrieben!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106856/discussion-between-nico-and-akuzminykh).

Comment: Da ich genügend Reputation habe, kann ich sehen, dass diese Antwort zum jetzigen Stand genau 0 Upvotes und 1 Downvote hat!

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Dass ich aufgrund dieser sinnlosen Unterstellung mein upvote zurückgenommen habe, dürfte klar sein, oder?

Comment: @Nico Das Gerangel nebenher macht doch die Antwort nicht schlechter...

Comment: @Lykanion Ich fand die Antwort gut.Siehe meinen ersten Kommentar! Was hätte es überhaupt für einen Sinn, eine Antwort für gut zu befinden und sie gleichzeitig zu downvoten, was mir ja unterstellt worden ist??

Answer (score 3):

> I like chess, but I haven't played for a while.

Translate in german: "**Ich mag Schach, aber ich habe schon *eine Weile* nicht mehr gespielt.**"

So '*in a while*' means a time over a period. But this period is not defined in a number of days or hours, just for a while.

The definition of 'a while' (eine Weile) in german, is as follows: "Zeitspanne von unbestimmter Dauer".

For use 'in a while' in your sentence, it would be like this:

> I like chess, but I haven't played it in a while.

Translate in german: "**Ich mag Schach, aber ich habe es schon lange nicht mehr gespielt.**"

Comment: Idiomatically, you would say "eine ganze Weile" to express that it's long ago, and not "eine Weile".

Comment: Whether you say "eine ganze Weile" or "eine Weile", I see no great difference... Depends on **HOW** to interpret "ganze". That's why I find it too petty, if you notice this here...

Comment: What should I "notice" here?

Comment: your first comment about „eine ganze Weile“ and „eine Weile“...

Comment: "Notice" means "become aware of something" and not "remark" by the way...

Comment: nooo excalation hahaha. But i find between „eine ganze Weile“ and „eine Weile“ no decisive difference, so I find your remark a little stingy...

Comment: What should I "notice" here? Besides, mine was just a remark. No reason for excalating :-) You should learn to accept other opinions.

Comment: @Nico: Man versuchte zu sagen: "Ich finde es zu kleinlich, wenn Du das hier thematisierst".

Comment: @userunknown Danke! Ich bin des Englischen mächtig genug. Ich habe meine Bemerkung gemacht, und das steht mir in einem Kommentar zu, glaube ich zumindest. Außerdem: "man versuchte"?

Answer (score 1):

Some possibilities with "Zeit":

> Ich habe (schon) **seit geraumer Zei**t nicht (mehr) gespielt.

This is a bit non-verbal style. It means "for quite some time".

---

> Ich habe (schon) eine (ganze) **Zeit lang** nicht (mehr) gespielt.

Or "eine Zeitlang", but this is bayrisch/austrian.

---

"eine Zeit lang" is not "eine lange Zeit":

> **Lange Zeit** ging das gut.
>
> *For a long time this worked.*
>
> Eine **Zeit lang** ging das gut.
>
> *For a (certain) while this worked.*

---

> Ich ha (schon) **es Ziitli** nüm gspiilt (*swiss german*)

I think Ziitli is a diminuitive (Zeitlein), and not a form of "Zeitlang".

The "nüm" is "nicht mehr" in the temporal sense: *not **any**more.*

---

Yet another way to combine long and time in German is:

**? Die Langezeit**

I was surprised to find it in duden.de. It is classified *schweizerisch*, though. I know it as fixed term plural "lange Zeiten":

> Ich ha **langi Ziite** nach deheim.
>
> *I have longings for home*

Which brings me back straight to OP:

Which one you mean:

- I really need a game of chess
- I do remember some of the rules